# User not added as collaborator is able to push/pull to private GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys, git-push, git-pull

I have two GitHub accounts (say `personnel` and `work`). I configured my `~/.ssh/config` file to work with [multiple accounts](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574). I created ssh key for `work` account and added the public key to my `work` GitHub account.

I created an organisation account and created a private repo. I can clone/push/pull to this private repo from my `work` account. Every time I push/pull I need to enter my password so I added ssh key running command `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work` and I can push/pull without entering password again and again. But the problem is after running `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work` somehow I can clone/push/pull this private repository from my `personnel` account which I think shouldn't be happening.

I am not sure what went wrong but it would be great if someone could guide me to right direction and tell me what I am doing wrong. Feel free to ask the relevant information if needed (Not a git/GitHub expert)

Config file details:

```
#Default GitHub (personnel account)
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

#Work Github
Host github_work
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

Command to add remote using `pesonnel` account:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:Organisation/hello.git
```

for `work` account:

```
git remote add origin git@github_work:Organisation/hello.git
```

Comment: You were supposed to use `github-COMPANY` as a hostname in place of `github.com` as described in the article. No `ssh-add` at any time.

Comment: @Ry- Yes. I did use `github-work` (in my case) as a hostname. All works good until I ran `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work`. I got this idea from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996).

Comment: SSH will try all keys in the authentication agent (`ssh-add`). This behavior is expected. I would recommend using Git over HTTPS and make use of Git's credential manager instead of Git over SSH, because SSH doesn't know which repo you're using and Git credential does (with `git config credential.useHttpPath true`).

Comment: @ephemient *"This behavior is expected"*: Strange! If `personnel` account is not added as collaborator to private repo then it should never access that repo that's what I expect.

Comment: To debug ssh issues : run `ssh -v github-personnel` you should see what keys are tried, in what order. `-vv` and `-vvv` will give you even more debugging insight.

Comment: @ephemient Also, could you please explain using Git over HTTPS in more detail?

Comment: GIt opens SSH which then uses the work key because keys are global to all SSH connections - SSH will try every key on every connection. https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/which-remote-url-should-i-use#cloning-with-https-urls

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/268776/74440

Comment: Unfortunately that won't help for GitHub, because all connections are to `git@github.com`.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure both remote repositories are referenced with SSH URLs

```
cd /paath/to/repo
git remote -v
```

If one of them is using HTTPS, then it would use the credentials (username/password) stored/cached in a credential helper, while the other would use the right passphrase-protected private key.

Second, you can try and test the same approach with private keys *not* passphrase-protected, to avoid having to deal with ssh-agent, just for testing.

Comment: I tried the `git remote -v`. Both are using `git@github`.

Comment: @haccks Then I need the content of the `~/.ssh/config` file as well as the exact command used to clone the `work` private repo using the `personnal` entry. (you can obfuscate the actual username/repo)

Comment: I updated the question with the details you asked for.

Comment: @haccks OK: suggestions: don't use github.com as Host entry. Use "`personal`". Don't use git@: never mention the user, it is already mentioned in each config Host entry. So then try `git remote add origin personal:Organisation/hello.git`, and see if you still can access the repo.